# Combinations of k elements from set N haskell

Tags: list, haskell, combinations

I am trying to get all ordered combinations of 3 elements from a set of `N`:
elements,that is : `["A","B","C","D"]` --> `["ABC","ABD","ACD","BCD"]`.

I thought about writing something like `[ x++y++z | pos(x)in list < pos(y) in list < pos(z) in list ]`

How would i do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You could write your function for **three** elements like using `tails :: [a] -> [[a]]`:

```
[x++y++z | (x:xs) <- tails list, (y:ys) <- tails xs, (z:_) <- tails ys]
```

This generates:

```
Prelude> :m Data.List
Prelude Data.List> (\list -> [x++y++z | (x:xs) <- tails list, (y:ys) <- tails xs, (z:_) <- tails ys]) ["A","B","C","D"]
["ABC","ABD","ACD","BCD"]
```

But usually you want a more **scalable solution** (one where you can generate combinations of *k* elements). You could for instance define a function `combinations :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]` like:

```
combinations 0 _ = [[]]
combinations n ls = [ (x:ys) | (x:xs) <- tails ls, ys <- combinations (n-1) xs ]
```

and then you have to `concat` all the elements (for instance using a `map`).

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
combinations 0 lst = [[]]
combinations k lst = do
    (x:xs) <- tails lst
    rest   <- combinations (n-1) xs
    return $ x : rest
```

Now, to get the result you want, use `map concat (combinations 3 ["A","B","C","D"])`.